# why IE DO NOT request with "If-None-Match"？

Tags: internet-explorer, etag

(1)step 1: after first request, web server response:

```
    HTTP/1.0 200 OK
    Date: Mon, 14 Jan 2013 02:20:51 GMT
    Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.8
    Cache-Control: max-age=0
    ETag: "LV50F29509"
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    X-Frame-Options: DENY
    X-Lvmi-Encoding: 16544/51562, 33%
    Vary: Accept-Encoding
    Content-Encoding: gzip
    Content-Length: 16544
    X-Cache: MISS from test.abc.com
    X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from test.abc.com:80
    Via: 1.0 test.abc.com (squid/3.0.STABLE20)
    Connection: keep-alive
```

(2)step 2: click the link in the page(link to the page itself), IE request with:

```
    GET /film HTTP/1.1
    Accept: /
    Referer: http://www.test.com/film
    Accept-Language: zh-cn
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; EmbeddedWB 14.52 from: http://www.bsalsa.com/ EmbeddedWB 14.52; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
    Host: www.test.com
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    Cookie: CX=1024; CY=712; ID=TEST
```

my question: why IE(8.0) DO NOT request with "If-None-Match"？

Comment: The Referrer is the same as the URL to be loaded. Does this make a difference? Did you press F5 to reload? Can you try manually entering the URL in a new tab?

Comment: not F5, I just click the link in the page, which link to the same page itself.

Comment: Do HTTP/1.0 support ETag?or {{X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from test.abc.com:80 X-Cache: MISS from test.abc.com}} is unexpected?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this probleme ? i have same

Answer (score 0):

It is a rather old question, but I thought it might be interesting to point to the following URL: [w3 - HTTP Etags and Friends](http://www.w3.org/1999/04/Editing/#2)

Your referenced strong etag seems to be a HTTP/1.1 feature. The question could be whether IE is considering this due to the HTTP/1.0 response?! Have you resolved your issue in the meantime?